# lightweight-charts Uncaught Error: Value is null

Tags: javascript, candlestick-chart, lightweight-charts

Lightweight Charts Version: **3.1.3**

I am using your chart for the cryptocurrency trade application in Vue project
but no matter what I get this error below is a sample code

**There is no duplicated or null data.**

```
import {createChart} from "lightweight-charts";
export default {
data() {
return {
                chartProperties: {
                  width: 700,
                  height: 300,
                  timeScale: {
                     timeVisible: true,
                     secondsVisible: false
                },
                layout: {
                    //backgroundColor: '#262C49', //Dark Theme
                    //textColor: '#80859E',
                    fontSize: 12,
                    fontFamily: 'irsans ,Calibri'
                }
            },
            chartData: [],
            candleSeries: null,
}
}
mounted() {

let cdata = [
{
close: 22750.76
high: 22759.53
low: 22750.25
open: 22752.8
time: 1608635340
},
....
];

this.chartElement = document.getElementById('chart');
this.chartProperties.width = this.chartElement.offsetWidth;
this.chart = createChart(this.chartElement, this.chartProperties);
this.candleSeries = this.chart.addCandlestickSeries();

this.candleSeries.setData(cdata);
```

Actual behavior:

The chart is drawn with no candlestick

[image]

and repeated error of Uncaught Error: Value is null

[image]

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/miladganjali/cmu5htpb/8/)

Comment: Are you data ordered by time in asc order?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you get this error **99%** chance that your data source has one of three problems

1. part of the data is null
2. there is duplication on data in timestamp
3. *my problem*: data should be ordered by time in ASC order, not in
   desc.

Comment: I had this error and it was because a timestamp from my line series went out of the range of the candlestick data.

Comment: Hi @user3388195, what do you mean by "timestamp went out of range of the candlestick data"? Is there any configuration that specify the range of the candlestick data?

Comment: Hi @Milad you save me lots of time. my problem was like yours.

Comment: Ordering by ASC solved it.

Answer (score -1):

if you're using an Object structure, aren't you forgetting the commas after adding a new element to the array?

```
let cdata = [
```

{
close: 22750.76,
high: 22759.53,
low: 22750.25,
open: 22752.8,
time: 1608635340,
},
....
]

because without the commas it seems to be a unique element in the object, which is not correct.